# Ler uma linha específica em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Olá.
Tenho um código em HTML que recebe uma informação lida de um QR Code, que contém informações como Cliente, Danfe, Código e Quantidade e as exibe dentro de uma textarea. Essa leitura é feita por meio de um aplicativo separadamente do código.
Segue o código HTML:

```
<div>
    <textarea type="text" id="dadosLidos" style="height: 250px; width: 700px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

O conteúdo dessa textarea é salvo em uma var no arquivo JavaScript e impressa no console logo após.

```
$scope.saveInfo = function() {
    var dados = document.getElementById("dadosLidos").value;  
    console.log(dados);
};
```

Um exemplo de informação que a textarea recebe é:

```
CLIENTE: FULANO DE TAL 
DANFE: 123456
CÓDIGO: 1234
QNT.: 2
```

O que eu preciso é ler apenas o conteúdo da terceira linha, ou seja, **CÓDIGO: 1234**. Vou fazer uma verificação com o código contido em cada QR Code. Como eu posso fazer para ler ou salvar em uma variável apenas o conteúdo da terceira linha, ou da linha CÓDIGO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplesmente faça um `split` por quebras de linha `\n`.

Você irá obter um vetor com todas as linhas do texto. O conteúdo da 3ª linha estará na posição 2:

```
const textoLido = `CLIENTE: FULANO DE TAL 
DANFE: 123456
CÓDIGO: 1234
QNT.: 2`;

vTexto = textoLido.split('\n');

linha3 = vTexto[2]
console.log(linha3);
```

Vai retornar:

```
CÓDIGO: 1234
```